# Some problems with installing JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Installed JupiterLab, but ran into a problem in the terminal.

```
> Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')
```

Tried the following commands:

1. First

`pip install pywinpty`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (0.5.7)
```

2. Second (version)
   Python --version 
   3.8.3
   jupyter-lab --version
   2.1.5
   ipython --version
   7.16.1
3. Third

`import winpty`

```
conda install pywinpty
```

and others don't get rid of startup errors

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it can be solved by installing `pywinpty` from the wheel provided here: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) .

Just download (the `wheel`) and install it via:

```
pip install -I the_wheel_name_you_have_downloaded
```